# How to get Missing entry using vlookup in libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice-calc, vlookup

I have 2 columns, A & B

With example data like below:

**A:A**

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

**B:B**

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9

I need a result in  Column C to look like:

**C:C**

> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9

I need to check Column A, for values that are not in Column B, and have the result in Column C.

how to achieve this using libreoffice vlookup

Comment: please post also some sample data, without that we don't understand your issue, therefore can't help.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I updated my question

Comment: `VLOOKUP` should be used when you have related data in the columns (e.g. you want to know Column B value, where column A is 3), this doesn't seem to be true for your case. Does the same numbers in the same row in your data? Do you need to fill column C from the top, or can data be in rows  next to the same one in column B?

Comment: @MátéJuhász how can I achieve  this

Comment: " how can I achieve this" what? I've asked some questions, without knowing the answer I don't understand your problem, so I can't help.

Comment: Notice that the two answers so far have very different approaches.  The question has a lot of ambiguity and could attract even more variations because it isn't clear what the data could look like or what you want the result to look like.  Are the two lists always in the same sequence or do you need to look for entries anywhere in any order?  Can the results just show the status next to each entry in the B column, or do you require only the exceptions, and must the exceptions be grouped contiguously as a new list?  (cont'd)

Comment: Can col A have values not in col B or just the other way around?  Your example is the opposite of your description.  All the ambiguity is likely to attract disparate answers, most of which will not solve the intended problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution. This will work even if you have numeric or text data in Column A & B. For this solution to work correctly start your data in Row 1, else a small manipulation using ROW function would be needed.

Sample data is in Cells A1:A5 & B1:B9.

Put the following formula in C1 and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in curly braces to indicate that it's any Array Formula. Drag it down along the length of Column B.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$9,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B$1:$B$9,$A$1:$A$5,0)),ROW($B$1:$B$9),9^99),ROW()))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Cell C1 Type:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IFERROR(FIND($B$1:$B$9,$A$1:$A$5)-1&"",$B$1:$B$9),ROWS($B$1:B1)),"")
```

Then Press Ctrl + Shift + Enter to make it an array formula,

Then drag it down.

[image]